# Delete a empty line from a File

Tags: c#, file, replace, line

I have a text file in which I add, update and delete data (**Contacts**). Each contact is in one line. Now when i delete a contact through my application, I am deleting a line in my file (*Replacing the contact with a empty string*) This is resulting a empty line in between contacts. I don't want this empty line. This is the piece of code that I wrote:

```
    private void btn_condel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bufferedListView1.Items.Clear();
        string fileContents = File.ReadAllText("C:\\sample.txt");
        string replacedContents = fileContents.Replace(txt_editname.Text + "@" + txt_editno.Text,"");
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\sample.txt", replacedContents);
        // Rest of the code
```

What do I need to do to eliminate this empty line while replacing the data in the file.

Comment: Do you have all of your contact lines in memory? If so, I think is better to rewrite everything at the end of the operations, not at every single action (add, delete, modify)

Comment: I display the contacts in a list view and these modification should be immediately shown in the list. So I cant do it as you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the easiest way to fix this would just be to grab the new line:

```
string replacedContents = fileContents.Replace(
    txt_editname.Text + "@" + txt_editno.Text + System.Environment.NewLine,"");
```

Comment: You can use [`System.Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Thanks, included it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 string fileContents = File.ReadAllText("C:\\sample.txt");
    string replacedContents = fileContents.Replace(txt_editname.Text + "@" +        txt_editno.Text,"");
    File.WriteAllText("C:\\sample.txt", replacedContents.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this should work: Read the file into a string array, convert it to a list (because you can't remove an item from an array), remove the contact and write the rest back to a file. That works even better if you parse the text file (btw: cant you use a XML file...?) into your own contact data type. Then you have a List and can delete an object from there.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\sample.txt");
List<string> list = lines.ToList<string>();
list.Remove(txt_editname.Text + "@" + txt_editno.Text);
File.WriteAllLines("C:\\sample.txt", list.ToArray());
```